# Passing variable between jobs in Azure Pipeline

Tags: variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

As it is not possible to pass a variable between stages in AzurePipeline, I'm trying to pass a variable between two jobs instead as it is explained in Azure documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch), however it wasn't successful and it returns an empty variable.

here is what I'm trying:

```
stages:
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: A
    displayName: TerraformDeploy
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment: 'test'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
       deploy:
        steps:
        - checkout: self
        - task: Bash@3
          displayName: 'Deploying Terraform'
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              cd environments/test
              terraform init
              terraform apply -var 'client_id=$(client-id)' -var 'client_secret=$(client-secret)' -var 'key_data=$(LinuxSSHPubKey)' -var 'tenant_id=$(tenant-id)' -auto-approve
              ip=$(terraform output public_ip_address)
              echo $ip   ###1.2.3.4
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myPubIP;isOutput=true]$ip"
            name: setvarStep

  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    variables:
      myIP: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['A.setvarStep.myPubIP'] ]
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          echo "ip:"$(myIP)   ### Empty variable!!
```

I've tried so many different things for this case but it hasn't been fixed so far, can anyone help with this?

Updated:

It seems someone else is also reported this issue and they are planning to fix it:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/769690/sharing-variables-between-jobs-not-working-for-dep.html

Even if I use both jobs as normal job, it still doesn't work for my case..

Comment: I have copied and adapted your yaml, and instead of AzureCLI I have used Bash task, variable was passed between jobs successfully. I suppose that something is wrong with AzureCLI@2 task(maybe cannot access variables) or with your'environment test'. Please check using Bash@3 in job B and check if variable is passed.

My yaml and result is in attached picture. Seems that it is not problem with using  'deployment' or 'job'.
 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rTmk.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very sure it is a paste format issue in the above YAML pipeline definition, and I saw the `ip` value has generated very successfully, it seems cause by the syntax of `name` in your YAML definition is not correct, so it is not correctly compiled as `reference name`.

Just go and confirm whether there has a yellow line under the `name`, like this:

[image]

If yes, **remove 2 space** before `name`, so that let it at the same level with `inputs`:

[image]

---

If I use the same definition with you, I also faced the issue of empty output variable. But if I did the change on space before `name`, then output variable can successfully get in job `B`.

So, you can have try with this on your side.